# Configuring IIS 7 SMTP settings via powershell

Tags: iis, smtp, powershell, iis-7

I need to touch up the list of IP addresses that can relay through my SMTP virtual server in IIS.  I've been trying to get a handle on what cmdlets and to use in my script but am struggling a bit.

Specifically I'm looking to modify the list of IP addresses that can relay through my server.  Should I be looking at the [IIS administration Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) for this or something else?  Any examples gladly accepted.